# How to call writeValue in Web Bluetooth with Wireshark (Reverse engineer bluetooth device)

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering, web-bluetooth

I'm trying to reverse engineer a bluetooth device so I can create my own app which can communicate to it.

I've managed to get Bluetooth logs from my Android phone and also been able to connect to the bluetooth device via web.

Unfortunately, whenever I try and write a value to a characteristic, I get an error:
`bluetooth.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: GATT operation failed for unknown reason.`

In Wireshark, the value that I have found in the write request is:
`0120030000000000`

How do I send this in Javascript?
I've tried the following, all of which don't work:

```
characteristic.writeValue(0x0120030000000000)
characteristic.writeValue(new Uint16Array([0x0120030000000000]));
characteristic.writeValue(new Uint8Array([0x0120030000000000]));
characteristic.writeValue(new Uint16Array([0x0120030000000000]));
characteristic.writeValue(new TextEncoder("utf-16").encode(0x0120030000000000));
```

I know the raw value is 0120030000000000, how can I send it via an ArrayBuffer?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that Wireshark has encoded the data in hexadecimal then you should create a `Uint8Array` like this,

```js
new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x20, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])
```

If it is convenient to express this data as a string in your program then you could write a function to build the `Uint8Array` by parsing the string two characters at a time.

Comment: Does this work for any device? I have a HM-17 module and would like to send a sequence of hex values to it. Tried in vain with many different setup. Last one was exactly yours? Am I missing something? Do we need to set the format to Uint8 ?

Comment: There is some ambiguity when you say "send a sequence of hex values". That could either mean that you have a sequence of hex values (as in my example) and you want to send the bytes those values represent to the device. It could also mean that the device expects hex values written in ASCII, i.e. the literal string `"0120030000000000"` from the original example. In that case you would use `new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode("0120030000000000")`. Either way, the Web Bluetooth API expects an `ArrayBuffer` (or a buffer view like `Uint8Array`) and will send its contents to the device.

Comment: I understand your point. Plenty of ambiguities. Sometimes you also think about a hex value being a reprensation of a char value etc. So that's why I use the expression "send hex value" as to me, a hex value is just a number. I am currently sending characteristic.writeValue(new Uint8Array([0xbb, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x04, 0x7e, 0x0A]), and I put 0x0A at the end of my value stream (hex value for "new line"), but it would not work. Seems I am doing something wrong. With the DSD bluetooth app I am sending the same sequence (as hex value(s)) and i get an immediate response